# Conflicting types for inet_ntop

Tags: sockets, winsock, mingw32, msys2, luasocket

I am trying to compile luasocket with Msys2 mingw32. When I run make I get this error message:

```
src\inet.h:48:13: error: conflicting types for 'inet_ntop'
48 | const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, socklen_t cnt);
  |             ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from src\wsocket.h:12,
             from src\socket.h:18,
             from src\inet.h:18,
             from src\luasocket.c:20:
C:/msys64/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/ws2tcpip.h:451:35: note: previous declaration of 'inet_ntop' was here
451 | WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE LPCSTR WSAAPI InetNtopA(INT Family, LPCVOID pAddr, LPSTR pStringBuf, size_t StringBufSize);
```

ws2tcpip is included in inet.h file. Do I need to set some different options to make this compile successfully in mingw?

Answer (score 1):

You're mingw32 environment is recent enough to have `inet_ntop()` in `ws2tcpip.h`, so `src\inet.h` shouldn't redefine it.

Try to remove `inet_ntop()` from `src\inet.h`.

If you get unresolved symbols errors related to socket function during the link phase you may need to add `-lws2_32` to the linker flags.